# How to detect and repair errors in mesh?

Tags: mesh

I downloaded a video game model. The problem is that although it appears to be a valid mesh, there are many many errors. For example, the mesh is not intact or manifold, or sometimes there's double faces, and double edges. There's many types of errors here, I think. Again it's not detectable by glancing at it. Just manually seeing what's wrong with a particular vertex, edge, or face would take forever, let alone repairing it individually. Is there a more efficient or systematic way to fix this mesh? I have attached pictures of 2 errors in the mesh. Thanks very much guys.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The operator is called `Select Non Manifold` in Mesh menu. It should help you  to find out weird mesh. With further configuration, you can choose what you want to inspect.

[image]

After you select those vertices, you still need to clean up them by hand or using operator again:

[image]

But don't rely on these method to fully fix your mesh since if your mesh is broken in some degree, that mesh will probably been so weird that algorithm can not figure how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks HiakriTW! After using the select non-manifold option, it seems that a huge part of my downloaded mesh has problems, even after I tried all of the options in the Clean Up menu. Anything else you or anyone else might suggest? Thanks again!

Comment: If the download source dose specified what 3D program they use to create that file, then go using that program instead of Blender. Since most of the model in commercial product will probably use thing instead of Blender, and the file format will poorly support by Blender importer function

Comment: You can also check your import option, there should be a lot of option in the bottom left hand side corner when importing.

Answer (score -2):

I came up with a solution. There were too many errors of different types in that mesh, so I exported the model as an STL. Then I went to [Netfabb.com](https://netfabb.com), which offers free STL mesh repairs, which has always worked for me. I uploaded the file and then Netfab corrected it for me as an STL, and then I went back to Blender and imported the fixed STL. And it worked. No more non-manifolds, double faces, double edges, or any other errors. Netfab has always worked for me in CAD, and now even in Blender.